# Ansible: How to convert shell command output into items or variables

Tags: ansible

I am running shell command in my playbook to extract the results of a command. The output of

```yaml
- debug: msg="{{ dblist.stdout_lines }}"
```

is

```yaml
ok: [host] => {
    "msg": [
"inst1:db1"
"inst1:db2"
"inst1:db3"
"inst2:db4"
"inst2:db3"
  ]
}
```

I need to store this value in a format that allows me to run my next playbook considering the value of item.0 as inst1 and item.1 as db2 and so on.

Currently

```yaml
- debug: msg="{{ item.0 }} has  a value {{ item.1 }}"
  with_items: "{{ dblist.stdout_lines }}"
```

is giving values like

```yaml
ok: [host] => (item=inst1:db1) => {
    "msg": "i has  a value n"
}
ok: [host] => (item=inst1:db2) => {
    "msg": "i has  a value n"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ _key }} has a value {{ _val }}"
      loop: "{{ dblist.stdout_lines }}"
      vars:
        _arr: "{{ item.split(':') }}"
        _key: "{{ _arr.0 }}"
        _val: "{{ _arr.1 }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: inst1 has a value db1
  msg: inst1 has a value db2
  msg: inst1 has a value db3
  msg: inst2 has a value db4
  msg: inst2 has a value db3
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're on a new enough version (ansible-core>=2.11), you can use the `split` filter:

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0 }} has a value {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ dblist.stdout_lines | map('split', ':') }}"
```

It's possible to achieve a similar result on older versions, but it's uglier:

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0 }} has a value {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ dblist.stdout_lines }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: _item
      vars:
        item: "{{ _item.split(':') }}"
```